# What does the hint "consider using 'strtol' instead" given by `clang-tidy` mean?

Tags: c, integer, printf, scanf

The `clang-tidy` program shows me a hint and I don't know what it means:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Initializing:
    char userName[12];
    int userDOB;
    // Developing:
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    // Taking the userName:
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR USER-NAME:");
    scanf("%s", userName);
    // Taking the userDOB:
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR USER-DOB:");
    scanf("%i", &userDOB);
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    // Printing data:
    printf("USER-NAME: %s \n", userName);
    printf("USER-DOB: %i \n", userDOB);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The hint is:

> Clang-Tidy: 'scanf' used to convert a string to an integer value, but function will not report conversion errors; consider using 'strtol' instead

This occurs in the scanf of the userDOB.

Comment: The suggestion is to read the input for `userDOB` as a string, and use `strtol` to convert to an integer. This will have much more validation of the input to make sure that it's really a valid integer. And even if you continue to use `scanf` to read the strings, you really should check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: See [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537)

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised that clang-tidy is yapping at you about that, but what it's telling you is something that very many C programmers have concluded: despite its superficial attraction, `scanf` is very nearly completely useless.  Most experienced C programmers don't use it, ever, for anything.

Comment: See also: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf.

Comment: scanf is good for reading text files containing fixed-format records.

Comment: @stark ... _no it isn't_. That's the point of all those links Steve posted.  It's broken as specified and should not be used at all.

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL ❤️♥️❤️